# I'm having trouble extracting a particular string with VBS

Tags: vbscript, split

I have a piece of code that successfully extracts a particular string using Split. I want to get a different string and I'm not getting the correct output.

This is the data I'm trying to extract the string from.

```
N126(Total: 476.00 in, 119.0 sq.in, 1 cu.in, .003 lb)
```

Currently I'm able to extract the 1 between sq.in, and cu.in, using this line of code.

```
volume = Split(Split(srtContents, "sq.in,")(1), "cu.in,")(0)
```

Instead of the 1 I would like to get the 119.0 but I always get 119.0 sq.

I know why I'm getting it I just don't know how to fix it. This is my code:

```
area = Split(Split(srtContents, "in,")(1), "sq.in,")(0)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this data. I'd imagine that splitting on a space and testing for a number would get you the numbers. The string 1 place above each number is going to be its label.

Comment: `Split(srtContents,"in,")(1)` does not contain the `"sq.in,"` string… Use e.g. `Split(srtContents," in,")(1)` instead (note a space).

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the total weight of composite material used to make a particular part. I'm trying to use the square inches to calculate the volume x the density. There can be up to 150

Comment: separate machine control data files, from where that line came from, to make a particular part. I have a script that is suppose to open each file, calculate the weight, then add them all up to get a total weight.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be splitting the input string at commas followed by a space:

```
s = "N126(Total: 476.00 in, 119.0 sq.in, 1 cu.in, .003 lb)"
a1 = Split(s, ", ")
```

then split the field you're interested in at spaces:

```
a2 = Split(a1(1), " ")
v = a2(0)
```

A more elegant approach, particularly when you want to extract several values from the string, would be a regular expression match, though.

```
s = "N126(Total: 476.00 in, 119.0 sq.in, 1 cu.in, .003 lb)"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(\d+\.\d+) in, (\d+\.\d+) sq\.in, (\d+) cu\.in, (\.\d+) lb"

For Each m In re.Execute(s)
    total  = m.Submatches(0)
    area   = m.Submatches(1)
    volume = m.Submatches(2)
    weight = m.Submatches(3)
Next

WScript.Echo area
```

Or, if you want to take a more generic approach:

```
s = "N126(Total: 476.00 in, 119.0 sq.in, 1 cu.in, .003 lb)"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = " ((?:\d*\.)?\d+) "
re.Global  = True

For Each m In re.Execute(s)
    WScript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
Next
```

Beware that either way the extracted values are still strings. If you need them as numeric values you need to convert them after the extraction, e.g. `weight CDbl(m.Submatches(3))`.